# Change header color after scrolling - problem with scroll mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code is perfectly working on the desktop version, but it doesn't work on mobile, I don't figure why. I also tried to deactivate the script on the mobile width, but it doesn't work either.

```
if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)")) {

  $(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $header = $(".header");
      $header.toggleClass('scrolling-active', $(this).scrollTop() > $header.height());
    });
  
    $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $logo = $(".logo");
      $logo.toggleClass('scrolling-logo', $(this).scrollTop() > $logo.height());
    });

    $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $menu = $(".menu");
      $menu.toggleClass('scrolling-menu', $(this).scrollTop() > $menu.height());
    });
    
  });
```

Here is a video of the issue (I have an AOS animate problem on mobile too, I'm working on that).
https://youtu.be/sA5Z0yOvZ_I

Answer (score 0):

Your first line of code literally contains `min-width: 768px` which is in an if statement. So, the if won't run on mobile.

Remove the if statement for it to work for both of them -

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $header = $(".header");
      $header.toggleClass('scrolling-active', $(this).scrollTop() > $header.height());
    });
  
    $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $logo = $(".logo");
      $logo.toggleClass('scrolling-logo', $(this).scrollTop() > $logo.height());
    });

    $(document).scroll(function () {
      var $menu = $(".menu");
      $menu.toggleClass('scrolling-menu', $(this).scrollTop() > $menu.height());
    });
```

`min-width` means that the minimum width of the window should be 768px. That is not the case for mobiles. When developers make a website responsive, they don't use `min-width`, they use `max-width` (for your case (768px)).

Comment: Thank you man, didn't know that. But the problem was not solved, the class changes only when the user scrolls until the end of the section. I don't know why

Comment: that is a different topic